# Best approach to intercept task creation in Activiti for updating a parallel search index?

Tags: java, workflow, mybatis, activiti

We are embedding Activiti in an application and have some specific requirements towards searching for tasks that go beyond the out of the box Task query capabilities of Activiti. I'm currently considering integrating ElasticSearch and maintaining a specialized index of tasks. For that to work I need to intercept task creation in Activiti.

I haven't found a "native" and transparent (in that I should not have to explicitly model this into my workflows) Activiti mechanism for this (like an interceptor mechanism). At the moment my best bet looks to be to write an myBatis intercepter plugin.

Before I commit to this I wanted to make sure I'm not missing a cleaner/easier method.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a post about this. Check out http://developer4life.blogspot.com/2012/02/extending-task-service-in-activiti.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDI (Weld), have a look at the Activiti User Guide, section "Receiving Process Events": http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#N12DA5